# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto\Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'

Tags: java, spring-data

Olá, tenho o seguinte trecho de código no meu context.xml:

```
<prop key = "hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

Mas quando coloco a propriedade *validate* no lugar de create da a seguinte exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
ERROR: Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'.


 jul 31, 2018 9:06:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApasiSpringMVC2-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1132)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1021)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5397)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 32 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:207)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:126)
        ... 43 more

    jul 31, 2018 9:06:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    GRAVE: Servlet [ApasiSpringMVC2] in web application [/apasi-spring-mvc2] threw load() exception
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:207)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1132)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1021)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5397)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    jul 31, 2018 9:06:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\FÁBIO\workspace003\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\apasi-spring-mvc2.xml has finished in 7,627 ms
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 8662 ms
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'ApasiSpringMVC2'
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:25 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
    INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:26 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:26 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:26 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: Invalid object name 'sys.sequences'.
    jul 31, 2018 9:06:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApasiSpringMVC2-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
```

Aqui a Entidade SiteUsuario, tem outras mas todas no mesmo padrão.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SiteUsuario")
public class SiteUsuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ROLE", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "siteUsuario", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Caixa> caixas;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public List<Caixa> getCaixas() {
        return caixas;
    }

    public void setCaixas(List<Caixa> caixas) {
        this.caixas = caixas;
    }

}
```

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar o código de suas classes mapeadas? Além disso, qual a versão do Hibernate você está usando?

Comment: Certo estou colocando...

Comment: Editei, coloquei umas das Entidades...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema foi o tipo de dialeto:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</prop>
```

Eu estou usando um banco de dados sqlserver 2008 e estava usando o Dialeto para 2012.

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop>
```

Percebi o erro, corrigi e ficou tudo ok.